# ODBC -> MySQL Sync

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, odbc

I am looking for a tool that can sync tables from an ODBC data source to a remote MySQL database on a scheduled frequency (or real-time). Does such a tool exist?

I found [DBTools Manager](http://www.dbtools.com.br/EN/dbmanagerpro/), but I don't believe this is a "hands-free" utility.

---

Note: The [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) data source is on [Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/) and the [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) server is on [CentOS](https://www.centos.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the remote MySQL database server OS, if Linux/CentOS, you can set up a crontab entry on said server to your scripts to SELECT from the source database locally, then DROP/CREATE/INSERT into the destination MySQL server database, after setting up the odbc.ini file on the Linux server first.

Comment: The ODBC data source is on Windows and the MySQL server is on CentOS. Can you explain further what is necessary for the `odbc.ini` file to connect the two machines?